# Python import txt formatting

Tags: python, string, import, text-files

I have an Excel file with a list of numbers and I saved it as a `.txt` file and then went to say:

```
open_file = open('list_of_numbers.txt','r')

for number in open_file:
    number = int(number)
    while x < 20000:
        if (x > number):
            print number
        x = x + 100
        y = y + 100
```

And I received this error message:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2100.00\r\n'

How can I strip the `'` and the `\r\n'`?

My ultimate goal is to create another column next to the column of numbers and, if the number is 145 for example,

```
145, '100-199'
167, '100-199'
1167, '1100-1199'
```

that sort of output.

Comment: The problem is not the new line character, the number is not an integer. It is a float value. Use `float()`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's put it as an answer. The problem is not `\r\n`. The problem is that you try to parse string that contains a float value as an integer. See (no line feed, new line characters):

```
>>> int("2100.00")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2100.00'
```

*(as you can see, the quotation marks `'` are not part of the value, they just indicate that you are dealing with a string)*

whereas

```
>>> int("2100\r\n")
2100
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) says:

> If the argument is a string, it must contain a possibly signed decimal number representable as a Python integer, possibly embedded in whitespace.

where the Python integer literal definition can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals).

**Solution:**

Use [`float`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float):

```
>>> float("2100.00\r\n")
2100.0
```

then you can convert it to an integer if you want to (also consider [`round`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round)):

```
>>> int(float("2100.00\r\n"))
2100
```

Converting a float value to integer works (from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int)):

> Conversion of floating point numbers to integers truncates (towards zero).

Answer (score 1):

To address your immediate problem, go with the answer by @Felix Kling.

If you are interested in your FUTURE problems, please read on.

(1) That `\r` is not part of the problem IN THIS PARTICULAR CASE, but is intriguing: Are you creating the file on Windows and reading it on Linux/OSX/etc? If so, you should open your text file with "rU" (universal newlines), so that the input line on Python has only the `\n`.

(2) In any case, it's a very good idea to do `line = line.rstrip('\n')` ... otherwise, depending on how you split up the lines, you may end up with your last field containing an unwanted `\n`.

(3) You may prefer to use [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org) to read from an Excel file directly -- this saves all sorts of hassles. [Dis]claimer: I'm the author of xlrd.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
number = int(number.strip(string.whitespace + "'"))
```

You will need to add `import string` to the beginning of the your script. See also: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

Comment: That does not work, try `int("2100.00\r\n".strip(string.whitespace + "'"))`.

Comment: Hello hello ... the `'` is non-existent; the exception is showing `repr(the_input_string)`